# How to debug `podman unshare` commands / Podman permission issues?

Tags: permissions, containers, podman, volumes, unshare

I understand that [`podman unshare`](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-unshare.1.html) can be used to properly set the permissions on unprivileged containers.
So `podman unshare chown 1234:1234 -R /home/user/volume` can be used to set the volume to the properly mapped ids.

But I'm getting permission errors when I'm trying to do that:

```bash
podman unshare chown -R 1234:1234 -R /home/user/foo/bar;  echo $?
chown: changing ownership of '/home/user/foo/bar': Operation not permitted
1
```

The first thing I thought about was directory permissions but it fails even if I'm giving the destination directory `0777`.
I'm calling the command as user `user` and the parent directories have these permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x root /home
drwxr-x--- user /home/user
drwxrwxrwx user /home/user/foo
drwxrwxrwx user /home/user/foo/bar
```

It isn't my intention to really use `0777` in production but something is off even with `0777` and it's not clear to me how to debug this.

Comment: What result do you get when running the command `podman unshare cat /proc/self/uid_map`?

Comment: One idea could also be to check if it is related to the file system used. You could for instance perform a similar test somewhere under _/tmp_ to see if you can get it working there. (_/tmp/_ and _/home/_ are often located on different file systems)